# SELECT Column1 FROM tablename in Django

Tags: django

Okay I know this is really stupid.But how to i write `SELECT Column1 FROM tablename`
I know i can use `Court.objects.all()[0]` to get just one row.But how do I get one column only(the whole column values).Am I missing something?

Also in `Court.objects.all()[0]` isn't it first retrieved and then spliced.So isn't it kinda inefficient.

Comment: Can anyone explain what this mean.The **Note** just above **only**.[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#only]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Court.objects.values_list('column_name', flat=True)
```

And if you write `Court.objects.all()[0]` only one row is [retireved](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets).

Answer (score 0):

```
Court.objects.only('column_name')
```

Comment: Actually it is a class. Django used this to for database query.